# Predefined UserControl or Control Size

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

Im trying to implement a control or usercontrol that has predefined sizes (width and height).

I have an enumeration with defined sizes:

```
public enum ControlSizes
{
    // Width x Height
    ControlSizeA, // 310 x 220
    ControlSizeB, // 310 x 450
    ControlSizeC // 310 x 680
}
```

Then in my control I have defined a DependencyProperty and a callback method to allow Size specification:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
        ("ControlSize", 
        typeof(ControlSizes), 
        typeof(CustomControl), 
        new PropertyMetadata(ControlSizes.ControlSizeA, OnControlSizePropertyChanged));

public ControlSizes ControlSize
{
    get { return (ControlSize)GetValue(ControlSizeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ControlSizeProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnControlSizePropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CustomControl customControl = source as CustomControl;
    Size controlSize = ControlSizeConverter.ConvertToSize(customControl.ControlSize);
    customControl.Width = controlSize.Width;
    customControl.Height = controlSize.Height;
}
```

The main idea is to have predefined sizes and in design-time be able to select one size, laid controls in that available size.

The problem is that width and height are not being saved or assigned properly.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `customControl.ViewSize`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Its:Size controlSize = ControlSizeConverter.ConvertToSize(customControl.ControlSize);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ControlSizeConverter.ConvertToSize` gets a `ControlSizes` object and returns a `Size`, And you want the `CustomControl` to adjust it size when the `ControlSize` DP changes, I think your callback should look like this:

```
private static void OnControlSizePropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CustomControl customControl = source as CustomControl;
    Size controlSize = ControlSizeConverter.ConvertToSize(ControlSize);
    customControl.Width = controlSize.Width;
    customControl.Height = controlSize.Height;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats exactly how I have it. The problem is that You set a ControlSize but the properties Width and Height are not changed. The size of the control appears to be taking the size but the properties arent. If You close and reopen the designer the change is not applied.